# CSS - Flexbox child height of parent (multi-column)

Tags: html, css

There are a lot of examples explaining how to get a flexbox child 100% the height of it's parent but when I add multiple column the various strategies don't work.

The code below ends up stacking the boxes on top of each other, they should be side by side.

[https://jsfiddle.net/pqmv4pc4/](http://jsfiddle.net/pqmv4pc4/)

```css
#snippet-container {
      height: 300px;
      width: 200px;
    }
    
    #page {
      display: flex;
      flex-flow: column;
      height: 100%;
    }
    
    #content {
      display: flex;
      height: 100%;
      background: blue;
      width:50%;
    }
    
    #content .test {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background: yellow;
      border: 2px solid red;
    }
```

```html
<div id="snippet-container">
          <div id="page">
          
            <div id="content">
              <div class="test"></div>
            </div>
          
             <div id="content">
              <div class="test"></div>
            </div>
                
          </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Everything on the CSS you wrote make it clear that you need them above each other, so why you think they need to be side by side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### `#page` should be `flex-flow: row;` not column.

```css
#snippet-container {
  height: 300px;
  width: 200px;
}

#page {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
  height: 100%;
}

#content {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  background: blue;
  width:50%;
}

#content .test {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: yellow;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="snippet-container">
  <div id="page">
  
    <div id="content">
      <div class="test"></div>
    </div>
  
     <div id="content">
      <div class="test"></div>
    </div>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: flex-flow: row; or better flex-direction: row; is by default, no need to explicitly define it.

Comment: Sure, but no harm in defining it for the OP

Answer (score 0):

Is this wat u want?

The default **flex-direction** of flex container is **row**, that means all its children will be arranged in row.

Also, The flex-flow property is a shorthand property for the following properties:

```
flex-direction
flex-wrap
```

```css
#snippet-container {
  height: 300px;
  width: 200px;
}

#page {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
}

#content {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  background: blue;
  width: 50%;
}

#content .test {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: yellow;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="snippet-container">
  <div id="page">

    <div id="content">
      <div class="test"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="content">
      <div class="test"></div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```